# What's the locale for Bahasa / Indonesia and Tagalog / Philippines? Is it id_ID and tl_PH?

Tags: internationalization, locale, multilingual

What's the locale for Bahasa / Indonesia and Tagalog / Philippines? Is it id_ID and tl_PH?

I saw that some sites mention in_ID but I believe "in" for locales is India.

Comment: `in` is in the [IANA database](http://www.iana.org/assignments/language-subtag-registry/language-subtag-registry) as a deprecated alias of `id` which may explain why you've seen it. But as your answerer says, `id` is preferred/correct for Indonesian as it's ISO.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @Tim That's helpful!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ISO 639-1 tag for [Bahasa Indonesia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indonesian_language) is `id`. Strictly speaking, you don't need to add a country or region tag. However, if you insist on adding an ISO 3166 code, that would be `ID`, so the resulting tag would be `id-ID`.

I am not aware of a language tag `in` in ISO 639-1. `IN` is the country code for India.

The ISO 639-1 tag for [Tagalog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagalog_language) is `tl`. You *can* add the ISO 3166 code for the Philippines, `PH`, which would result in `tl-PH`.

For an official list of ISO 639 codes, see [Codes for the Representation of Names of Languages](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/English_list.php) at the Library of Congress (USA). For country codes, see the [Online Browsing Platform for ISO 3166](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#search). For the current convention for using these types of codes, see [IETF BCP 47: Tags for Identifying Languages](https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47).

Comment: Thanks @christophe!

Comment: in JDK documentation i see the language tag as "in-ID"  for Indonesia https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk14-suported-locales.html#cldrlocale

Comment: @resatz That's an interesting point. The JDK locales don't always correspond to the ISO language tags. For example, Hebrew is `he` in ISO 639 but `iw-IL` in the JDK docs.